# How to iterate an object into an array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extjs

I have create one object and that object I need to pass in one method where I need to iterate by using each object. Since my Obj having only values so it its not getting passed. Can any one help me into this.

My Code :

```
var MyObj = {
    country : "Aus",
    Time : "EST",
    Val : "Pecific"
}
```

Now this MyObj I need to pass in one method:

```
this.someMethod(id, MyObj);
```

In someMethod i Have one code like

```
Ext.Array.forEach(MyObj, function (Value) {})
```

At this point it is getting failed because `MyObj` is not an array of object. How to correct it.

Comment: Object.keys(MyObj)

Comment: Where I need to use that.

Answer (score 3):

**It would be very helpful if you'd provide more information.**

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but there are several ways to iterate through objects.

If you want to split up your object into multiple single-key objects:

```
> Object.keys(MyObj).map(key => ({ [key]: MyObj[key] }))
[ { country: 'Aus' }, { Time: 'EST' }, { Val: 'Pecific' } ]
```

On the other hand, if you have a function that takes an array but you want to pass just this one object:

```
Ext.Array.forEach([MyObj], Value => ())
```

(But in this case you are better off just calling the function.)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var MyObj = {
    country : "Aus",
    Time : "EST",
    Val : "Pecific"
}

//Without ext
function someMethod(id, MyObj)
{
  Object.keys(MyObj).forEach(function (Value) {
console.log(MyObj[Value]);
});
}

someMethod(1, MyObj);
```

This code (vanilla JS) will get the keys from the Object with `Object.keys` and allows you to iterate over it. Works for Objects and Arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that in the following way:

```js
var MyObj = {
    country : "Aus",
    Time : "EST",
    Val : "Pecific"
}

function someFunction(id, obj){
  var objArray = $.map(obj, function(el) { 
    console.log(el);
    return el 
  });
}
someFunction(1, MyObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why are you introducing a library like jQuery to do something that can be handled by Vanilla JS?

Answer (score 3):

## The ExtJs way

ExtJs provides `Ext.Object.eachValue` which is what you are searching for.
From the [ExtJs documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Object.html#method-eachValue):

> Iterates through an object and invokes the given callback function for
>   each iteration. The iteration can be stopped by returning false in the
>   callback function.

The following code iterrates over each value of `MyObj` and calls the callback with it.

```
var MyObj = {
    country : "Aus",
    Time : "EST",
    Val : "Pecific"
}

Ext.Object.eachValue(MyObj, function (Value) {console.log(Value)});
```